# cannot change content inside span tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to be able to target the current input and the sibling `<span>` tag and change the text of this span to OK or NOT OK, depending if the input is empty or not.

I can now only target the first span with selecting the key [0]. How do I make this code so it targets the CURRENT span? so span 1,2 or 3.

My jsfiddle does not work, the code works raw in my notepadd++. Maybe I forgot something to start the code?

https://jsfiddle.net/26u5efzc/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Opdracht 2: Onze Taal</title>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkNotEmpty(formField){ //maak functie aan geef parameters mee
        if(formField.value.length > 0){ //als waarde ongelijk is aan 0 dan
            console.log("OK"); //log OK
            document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML = "OK";
            return true;

        }
        else {
            console.log("NOT OK");
            document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML = "NOT OK"
            return false;
        }
    }
    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("naam").onblur = function(){
            checkNotEmpty(this);
        };
        document.getElementById("email").onblur = function(){
            checkNotEmpty(this);
        };
        document.getElementById("vraag").onblur = function(){
            checkNotEmpty(this);
        };
    };

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <figure>
        <img src="onzeTaal.jpg" alt="Onze Taal" title="Onze Taal" />
        <figcaption>Onze Taal</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <form name="taalvraag" method="get" action="#">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Stel uw vraag</legend>
            <label for="naam">Uw naam:</label>
            <input type="text" name="naam" id="naam" placeholder="naam" />
            <span class="melding" id="meldingNaam">1</span>
            <br />
            <label for="email">Uw e-mailadres:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="e-mail" />
            <span class="melding" id="meldingEmail">2</span>
            <br />
            <label for="vraag">Uw vraag:</label>
            <input type="text" name="vraag" id="vraag" placeholder="vraag" />
            <span class="melding" id="meldingVraag">3</span>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="verzenden" id="verzenden" value="Verzenden" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1) the code in the question doesn't match the jsfiddle; you have `window.onload` in one and `document.ready` in the other. 2) jsfiddle already puts everything in a window.onload event by default so your code will never trigger because the event is already gone.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update from

```
 document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML
```

to

```
formField.nextElementSibling.innerHTML
```

Updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/26u5efzc/1/

Answer (score 0):

fixed the issue with the following, making a new parameter and using this to find the current input and span element

```
function checkNotEmpty(veld, melding){ //maak functie aan geef parameters mee
        if(veld.value.length != 0){ //als waarde ongelijk is aan 0 dan
            console.log("OK"); //log OK
            melding.innerHTML = "OK";
            return true;

        }
        else {
            console.log("NOT OK");
            melding.innerHTML = "NOT OK";
            return false;
        }
    }
    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("naam").onblur = function(){
            checkNotEmpty(this, document.getElementById('meldingNaam'));
        };
        document.getElementById("email").onblur = function(){
            checkNotEmpty(this, document.getElementById('meldingEmail'));
        };
        document.getElementById("vraag").onblur = function(){
            checkNotEmpty(this, document.getElementById('meldingVraag'));
        };
    };
```